# Good Reference for Large Cardinals/Homotopy Theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, homotopy-theory, large-cardinals

I'm planning on attending a conference in Barcelona in September called "Large Cardinal Methods in Homotopy Theory" and want to try to be as prepared as I possibly can. Are there good references for this sort of thing other than scholarly papers (a lot of the work is stuff done by Carles Casacuberta et.al.).  I'm learning a lot of large cardinals and homotopy theory already, but I'd like to understand better what is meant by "Large Cardinal Methods."  Is that like... forcing?  What is that?

Thanks!!
Jon

Comment: This might not be what you're looking for but there is a link between braid groups and large cardinals. Some problems in involving braid groups were solved using large cardinals. See: http://spot.colorado.edu/~szendrei/BLAST2010/miller_new.pdf

Comment: You can also see this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35281/category-and-homotopy-theoretic-methods-in-set-theory

Comment: After reading the title I immediately thought of Vopenka's principle and its uses in model theory. The best known work is due to Rosicky and Tholen which you can find easily by Googling. A very accessible source for Vopenka's principle (pun accidental) is [Adamek-Rosicky](http://books.google.com/books?id=q742EvMEKTwC) (which should be good to have at hand at that conference anyway). A more set-oriented exposition of Vopenka's principle is in Jech's [set theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=iX-UQgAACAAJ) if I remember well. Large cardinals are used for pushing the small object further.

Comment: Somehow I jumbled up my last sentence: I meant to say. Large cardinal principles can be used to push Quillen's small object argument further.... :)

Comment: I strongly suggest to find some papers in general topology or descriptive set theory in which large cardinals are used. This might give you a sense of non-consistency related proofs with large cardinals.